# Mongoose populate one field from another id field

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I am currently having 2 fields as follows in [typegoose](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/) (provides better typings for mongoose)

```js
class User {
  @prop()
  public car: Car; // This is a single Reference

  @prop()
  public carId: Ref<Car>; // This is a single Reference
}
```

Now when I try to use `populate` method of mongoose, it fills `carId` field from `Car` collection.

But I need to fill `car` field using `carId` reference. Is there a way to do this?

When I use both `Car | Ref<Car>` as type, it requires lot of conversion wherever used with either `<Car>cardId` or `carId as Car` which I need to avoid as it loses the purpose of typescript.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `public car: Car;` you are basically saying that this is a sub-document, which it is not, so the proper type would be `public car: Ref<Car>;`. As for options, you are probably searching for [Virtual Populate](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/api/virtuals#virtual-populate) where you use option `ref` to set the class (model name) which to use for this field, option `localField` for the path where to look for the id on the local document and `foreignField` as the remote path to compare the `localField` against.

Example:

```
class User {
  @prop({ ref: () => Car, localField: 'carId', foreignField: '_id', justOne: true })
  public car?: Ref<Car>; // This is now a virtual-populate

  @prop({ ref: () => Car })
  public carId?: Ref<Car>; // This is still a single reference, which can be populated, but should also be able to be used for virtual-populate
}
```

Note: You could also just define `carId` as `mongoose.Types.ObjectId` if you dont want it to be populate-able.

Note: The `justOne: true` is required, otherwise mongoose will *always* return a array for virtual-populate.